# Google Maps V2 showing blank screen on 4.4 with google logo showing in bottom left

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm going absolutely crazy here, I've been through so many posts, and nothing seems to be working. My device is definitely connection to play service as I've checked that, and my key is showing my application when I look under my api credentials. For some unknown reason to me, I can't seem to get it to display the map, just the blank screen, and I've spent a good 3 hours on it with no luck. Any help as to why I can't get the map to show would be hugely appreciated! I've even tried regenerating the keys with no luck.

AndroidMainifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.*****.****" >

<permission
    android:name="com.*****.****.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.*****.****.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="********-***********"/>

</application>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.zoome.natalie.zoo;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
GoogleMap googleMap;
// tag used on log messages.
static final String TAG = "HelloGooglePlayServices";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createMap();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    //auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    // You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
    checkPlayServices();

}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Device not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createMap() {
    try {
        if (null == googleMap) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.mapView)).getMap();

            /**
             * If the map is still null after attempted initialisation,
             * show an error to the user
             */
            if (null == googleMap) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
    }
}
}
```

And in case it's useful the build.gradle module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.zoome.natalie.zoo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
}
```

The debugging key is what I am most unsure of, but I think it's right, any help of what to try or where I've made a mistake would be so greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your api key value a reference from a strings.xml file ?I mean in your manifest  where you have <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="********-***********"/>  is it hardcoded ?

Comment: API was generated from Google Dev Console...

Comment: Yes, what I ask is if you have that value in a strings.xml file or you just typed it to the manifest? If it's in an strings.xml file did you check if you added the value for both debug and release version of you app ?

Comment: It seems you need to use `Google Maps V2` api, and use it to your app. Just try to following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, it will help you.

Comment: @bjiang there was one step in that i missed out originally so got hopeful it'd fix it but still the same issue. Thanks though, that videos really helped me understand it better! :)

Comment: some issue as blank screen？Thats wired. what network u use? Have u tried create a new project and try the video out?

Comment: Fixed it! It seems I had conflicting things to display it but it wasn't picking up that they were conflicting.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have SDK stuff installed (which I believe you do based on the fact that you get to the gray screen with the Google Logo) the first thing you'll want to do is create a debug and release keystore. The full documentation is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Here's the quick and dirty for a Mac / Linux user. In the terminal type the following:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

You should then see your SHA1 hash to be used for debug builds. Copy and paste that somewhere.

I'm not sure if you're at a point where you're trying to compile this app for a release yet, but let's go through the motions now and save you the headache down the road. In Android Studio click **Build -> Generate Signed APK**.

This will take you through a little walk-through process where you select the Module you want to compile and then select the key that you want to use for the module. At this point you want to click **Create New**

This will let you decide where you want to save your release key, make you set a password and there are a few other options you can set at that time.

Now **get the SHA1 hash for your release key** that by using the same keytool command as above but replacing the path to the file you just created and the password arguments for whatever you just used as your password.

Now go to

https://console.developers.google.com/project

Select your project and go to the **Credentials** link on the left. If you don't have one yet, make yourself a Public API Access Key for Android. If you do have one, click the **Edit Allowed Android Applications** button. Paste both of the SHA1 keys that you took note of earlier here and then put ';your.package.name' after each line. Now, copy an paste the API KEY somewhere.

Go back to Android Studio and find the google_maps_api.xml file in both your debug and release folders. The paths should be:

package/app/src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml
package/app/src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Open each of those up and paste in a strink like this:

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">API KEY</string>
```

Finally, go in your AndroidManifest and make it say this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Grab a beer and celebrate

Comment: Not having any luck :( Putting the string into the release maps api throws an error, and the same with the google_maps_key string

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? Can you paste the stack trace in your original post?

Comment: What was it that you had to change?

Comment: Originally I had it linking to google play twice, which appeared to be stopping it for some reason, so removed one of the lines of code declaring it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a blank screen (or with grids) on the view area of the map, Possibility is, You are using the API key for Version 1 and putting it inside your manifest. Please have a look at your developers console and look for Google Maps V2 key!!

Answer (score 0):

If you see a blank screen without any grid, with a google logo on your bottom left hand-side, most probably the API key that you created is not the
appropriate one, You should not create a simple API key but one which registers your application for Google Maps Android API in Google Developers Console.The proper link drives you to the "Enable an API page", here the link 
https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapiapiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&reusekey=true

both your manifest and layout look good to me, the MainActivity has nothing unusual....

Answer (score 0):

Please create the api key properly; the link below provides the required details:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Please make sure that you have enabled internet on your phone before running the app.